# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on boolean

Tags: php

Crashes on:

```
$Time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$DBTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', 2000-01-01 00:00:00, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$Interval = $DBTime ->diff($Time);
```

> Call to a member function diff() on boolean

Wrong format?

Comment: `'2000-01-01 00:00:00'`, see these quotes? And where is microseconds (`u` placeholder)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add date time string in to quotes also in format there is `u` for(microseconds) but it is not specified in string. So it will return false. change your code as below:

```
$Time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$DBTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$Interval = $DBTime ->diff($Time);
```

Answer (score 1):

`createFromFormat` returns FALSE because the format doesn't match with the time (that should be wrapped into quotes). The format is `Y-m-d H:i:s` instead of `Y-m-d H:i:s.u`:

```
$Time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$DBTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$Interval = $DBTime->diff($Time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can archive with this too

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$DBTime = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2000-01-01 00:00:00')));
$Time = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$Interval = date_diff($DBTime, $Time);
```

Comment: _"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '00' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ')'"_: String into `strtotime()`.

Comment: wrap with quotes `'2000-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: It's better like that ;)